Optimizing entropy of conditional Gaussians
this is a very specific problem, but i don't really know who to turn to to ask if my logic is correct, hence the post.
My problem is the following:
Let $V\in \{1,2\}$ be a random variable such that $P(V=1) = p_1$ and $P(V=2) = 1-p_1=p_2$.
Moreover, we define $X$ such that
$$
X|V=1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_1^2), \\
X|V=2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_2^2).
$$
(I will abreviate by writing $X_1, X_2$).
We want to maximize the following expression: $\max_{p_1, p_2, \sigma_1, \sigma_2}H(V) + h(X|V$), where $H$ denotes entropy and $h$ denotes differential entropy, subject to the constraint
$$
\sum_{i=1}^2 p_i\sigma_i = \alpha
$$
My idea is to expand the obective function into
$$
H(V) + h(X|V)  =  -\sum_{i=1}^2p_i\ln(p_i) - \sum_{i=1}^2p_ih(X_i) \\
     = \sum_{i=1}^2p_i\ln(\frac{1}{p_i}) +  \sum_{i=1}^2p_i\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi e \sigma_i^2}\right) \\
     =  \sum_{i=1}^2p_i\left(\ln(\frac{1}{p_i}) + \ln(\sigma_i) + \ln(\sqrt{2\pi e})\right) \\
     =  \sum_{i=1}^2p_i\ln\left(\frac{\sigma_i}{p_i}\right) + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi e)}_{=C} \\
    =  -\sum_{i=1}^2p_i\ln\left(\frac{p_i}{\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}}\right) + C + \ln(\sigma_1+\sigma_2) \\
     =  -\mathcal{D}\left(\mathbf{p}\|\mathbf{q}\right) +  C + \ln(\sigma_1+\sigma_2),
$$
Then, we can appeal to the constraint by letting
$$
p_i = \frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2},
$$
giving us that the solutions are on the circle defined by
$$
\frac{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1 + \sigma_2} = \alpha
$$
which maximize the $\ln$-term by setting $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 = \alpha$.
Somehow, i am doubting my logic, especially when it comes to 'solving' the part with the $p$-terms. Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

There seems to be a missing minus , the line after $- \sum_{i=1}^2p_ih(X_i)$

With Lagrange multipliers: $$J= \sum_i p_i \log (p_i \sigma_i) + \lambda \sum_i p_i + \beta \sum_i p_i \sigma_i$$
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial p_i}= \log (p_i \sigma_i) + 1 +\lambda + \beta \sigma_i$$
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \sigma_i}= \frac{p_i}{\sigma_i} + \beta p_i=p_i(\beta + \frac{1}{\sigma_i})$$
Equating both derivatives to zero, the latter implies
$$ \sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = -\frac{1}{\beta}$$
which plugged into the former gives $p_1 = p_2$.
Hence the only critical point is at $p_1 = p_2 = \frac12$ and $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = \alpha$
It remains to check that this is a maximum (and a global one).
